# SQL Server Trigger on Update (Only New Data)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quick question, we have a simple Trigger we need to use that Inserts into TableB for example if any 3 Columns (Lets call them c1,c2, or c3) get updated.

However i've seen Trigger examples that do this, but I DO NOT want it to Insert if c1,c2, or c3 get updated with the same information. It can only be new info.

I know there is the "AFTER UPDATE", but will this work if the same data is being placed in the columns (Because if so, I don't want that)

Comment: In an UPDATE trigger you have access to the old data in DELETED, and to the new data in INSERTED.  Add logic to compare the values of matching records, and only execute the INSERT if they are different.

Comment: So you're saying you only want the trigger to insert data into table B if new data is inserted, or data that is different than existing data in C1,2 or 3 is updated? If the update data is the same as what is already in C1,2 AND 3, skip the insert into table B?

Comment: Correct, I only want to insert data into table B if the Columns C1,C2 or C3 are updated with NEW data and not the same data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger. This one will allow you to see values as they were before update and what is being updated to.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsteadOfUpdateMyTable ON dbo.MyTable
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable
                ( col1
                ,col2
                ,col3
                )
                SELECT i.col1
                       ,i.col2
                       ,i.col3
                    FROM INSERTED i
                    JOIN MyTable s
                        ON i.id = s.id
                           AND ( i.col1 <> s.col1
                                 OR i.col2 <> s.col2
                                 OR i.col3 <> s.col3
                               )
        UPDATE t
            SET t.col1 = i.col1
               ,T.col2 = i.col2
               ,T.col3 = i.col3 
            FROM MyTable t
            JOIN INSERTED i
                ON i.id = t.id
    END
```

here is SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a249a/6